# SQL Server ODBC Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, linked-server, msdasql

I'm trying to create a linked server in SQL Server 2017, linked system is odbc (criteria criOdbc)

**Test 1** from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
select * 
from OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',
                'DSN=criteria64;uid=xxxx;pwd=yyyy;',
                'select * from table where key < 10')
```

I get this error

> Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBDATE to date

**Test 2** from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
select * 
from OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',
                'DSN=criteria64;uid=xxxx;pwd=yyyy;',
                'select key from table where key < 10')
```

This works perfectly

**Test 3** in C# (load from odbc then bulk insert into SQL Server):

```
OdbcConnection acc = new OdbcConnection("DSN=criteria64;uid=xxxx;pwd=yyyy;")
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select * from table where key<10", acc);
....
```

This again works perfectly

**Test 4** connect the same table in MS Access as a linked table:

This also works perfectly

**Conclusion**

- `Msdasql` (Provider OLE DB Microsoft for ODBC) doesn't work well with date and some other type .net
- System.Data.Odbc (.NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC) works perfectly

**Final question**

Is possible to use NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC in linked server? (can't find any documentation)

If not: is there any kind of connector (odbc based) that I can try to use in linked server as an alternative to `msdasql`?

**Note**
Casting every single date colum using a case statement is not a solution for me.
I'm searching for a global fix.

I also need to Write into this tables.

My more comfortable alternative in this case is use c#.

Thank you for your time

Comment: What's the difference between 1 and 2? By the way Linked server <> `OPENROWSET`

Comment: test 2, select only key (int) column instead of *, yes but linked server throws the same error ( under hood use msdasql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error converting dbtype\_dbdate to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487745/error-converting-dbtype-dbdate-to-date) Looks like you have an out of range date

Comment: @Charlieface , yes and no, could work but is not so clean, and must be applied on every single table, and I need also to write data not only read. I'm searching for a global fix